# Error when trying to retrieve the user location using Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, location, locationmanager

I want to create an application to get the user location info in coordinates using Locaion manager. The problem is my application always has stopped when it runs and always get java.lang.NullPointerException

this is my Main ACtivity

`package com.ionlab.project.volley;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.ionlab.project.volley.app.AppController;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    //location
    private TextView textView;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    //waktu
    TextView textviewDate;

    Button buttonChoose;
    FloatingActionButton buttonUpload;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ImageView imageView;
    EditText txt_name;
    EditText txt_item;
    Bitmap bitmap, decoded;
    int success;
    int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    int bitmap_size = 60; // range 1 - 100

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /* 10.0.2.2 adalah IP Address localhost Emulator Android Studio. Ganti IP Address tersebut dengan
    IP Address Laptop jika di RUN di HP/Genymotion. HP/Genymotion dan Laptop harus 1 jaringan! */
    private String UPLOAD_URL = "http://192.168.1.4/android/upload_image/upload.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    private String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
    private String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private String KEY_ITEM = "item";
    private String KEY_LOKASI = "lokasi";
    private String KEY_WAKTU = "waktu";


    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
        buttonUpload = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

        txt_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        txt_item = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editItem);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showFileChooser();
            }
        });

        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                uploadImage();
            }
        });

        //Calendar
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String currenDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());

        textviewDate = findViewById(R.id.text_view_date);
        textviewDate.setText(currenDate);

        //textloc
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_textview);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, bitmap_size, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }

    private void uploadImage() {
        //menampilkan progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Uploading...", "Please wait...", false, false);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());

                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                            success = jObj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                            if (success == 1) {
                                Log.e("v Add", jObj.toString());

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                kosong();

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        //menghilangkan progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //menghilangkan progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();

                        //menampilkan toast
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e(TAG, error.getMessage().toString());
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                //membuat parameters
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                //menambah parameter yang di kirim ke web servis
                params.put(KEY_IMAGE, getStringImage(decoded));
                params.put(KEY_NAME, txt_name.getText().toString().trim());
                params.put(KEY_ITEM, txt_item.getText().toString().trim());
                params.put(KEY_WAKTU, textviewDate.getText().toString().trim());
                params.put(KEY_LOKASI, textView.getText().toString().trim());


                //kembali ke parameters
                Log.e(TAG, "" + params);
                return params;
            }
        };

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, tag_json_obj);
    }

    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                //mengambil fambar dari Gallery
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                // 512 adalah resolusi tertinggi setelah image di resize, bisa di ganti.
                setToImageView(getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 512));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void kosong() {
        imageView.setImageResource(0);
        txt_name.setText(null);
        txt_item.setText(null);
    }

    private void setToImageView(Bitmap bmp) {
        //compress image
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, bitmap_size, bytes);
        decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes.toByteArray()));

        //menampilkan gambar yang dipilih dari camera/gallery ke ImageView
        imageView.setImageBitmap(decoded);
    }

    // fungsi resize image
    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
        if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
            width = maxSize;
            height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
        } else {
            height = maxSize;
            width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
        }
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        textView.setText("Longitude:" + longitude + "\n" + "Latitude:" + latitude);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}`

i also make sure that my android manifest is correct

I have Spent Day and Night trying to solve this problem, Browsed through numerous pages on the topic, Tried different codes of my own.
And it still happens. I am a beginner in Android. And please, please do help me. Is there no possible way to solve my problem?

this is my logcat
[LogCat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCbip.png)

Comment: Besides @Barns answer, please note that in the documentation it is stated that when you set the location settings off in your phone, the location value, which is stored in cache memory, is deleted.So when you again set location settings on and try to get location , through the location change listener, the value will be null for some time.Until the phone gets the location.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should include your logcat in text form as a part of your question!

However, from what I can read from your screenshot the issue is in the `onLocationChanged()` method. Perform a check on "location" to see if it is `null` before trying to read it.

```
@Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location != null){
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        textView.setText("Longitude:" + longitude + "\n" + "Latitude:" + latitude);
    }
    else{
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged -- location is null!");
    }
}
```

**Note:**

Just in case you didn't know the "TAG" is generally added to the beginning of most Android class like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

      private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
```

Why `MainActivity.class.getSimpleName()` instead of just "MainActivity"? Because if you ever refactor your code, then the name will automatically be changed.

**EDIT:**

Have you added the necessary permissions in your manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>
```

Comment: thank you Barns, Now there is No error in My Code But my Aplication is can't Retrive the user Location, Coordinate such as Longitude and Latitude Wont Appear

Comment: @laura :: Have you checked to see if your have requested the required permissions in your Manifest file?  You must also be certain that the permission was actually granted!

Comment: thank you Barns, Now there is No error in My Code But my Aplication is can't Retrive the user Location in Coordinate such as Longitude and Latitude Wont Appear, this is the logcat --> https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Srxq9qjK1JemHl8SoyECX5hBtTIX45FN

Comment: yes i have, all app permission is granted, But the user coordinat are now unable to appear

Comment: it is Xiaomi Device actually Xiaomi Redmi 4x

Comment: @laura :: Same results with Samsung?

Comment: @laura :: it seems that I am at a loss as to why you devices continue to return `null`. You might wish to have look at `FusedLocationProviderClient` which I use in my new projects. Sorry I could not help.